# Restoring Firebase apex domain key

Tags: ssl, dns, certificate, lets-encrypt, firebase-hosting

Is there a way to restore the domain key?

I removed the TXT record with the domain key from my DNS config, because I thought it would only be necessary for validating the ownership once. But then I found out it's needed for validating the SSL cert as well.

I tried to remove and add the domain again, and even removed the whole project. But since the domain is validated already, the validation step won't show up. So don't see any way to view the domain key again and my site doesn't get a certificate.

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I added the domain by using the advanced settings and put the acme challange token to my DNS record:

`_acme-challenge.app TXT <token>`

Now I got my certificate.